Debugging drupal 10 cache context
I found that I have a query cache context enabled on all pages on a Drupal 10 website. This is not default Drupal behavior.
I believe there is some custom code or module that enables this query cache context but I cannot find it. I found a configuration which is the default one : required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions'] so it is not the problem.
I want to remove this query cache context. Is there a way to know which module or custom code adds a specific cache context ?
